# How do i set the value of toggle buttons within teams?

Tags: flutter

How do i set the value of the toggle score buttons for each team ?

For example when team A is pressed then user can choose from score buttons. Also if team B is pressed then user can choose from score buttons. But only the team selected gets the points.

```
 void scoreTeamA() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamA += _choiceA;
    });
  }

 void scoreTeamB() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamB += _choiceB;
    });
  }
```

Team buttons

```
      ToggleButtons(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text(
              'team A',
              textScaleFactor: 3,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'team B ',
            textScaleFactor: 3,
          ),
        ],
        onPressed: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                buttonIndex < isSelected1.length;
                buttonIndex++) {
              if (buttonIndex == index) {
                isSelected1[buttonIndex] = true;
              } else {
                isSelected1[buttonIndex] = false;
              }
            }
          });
        },
```

Score buttons

```
 ToggleButtons(
                children: [
                  Text('5 points'),
                  Text('6 points'),
                  Text('7 points'),
                ],
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    isSelected2[index] = !isSelected2[index];
                    switch (index) {
                      case 0:
                        _choiceA = 5;
                        _choiceB = 5;
                        break;
                      case 1:
                        _choiceA = 6;
                        _choiceB = 6;
                        break;
                      case 2:
                        _choiceA = 7;
                        _choiceB = 7;
                        break;
                    }
                  });
                },
                isSelected: isSelected2,
              ),
```

Win Button

```
 MaterialButton(
                  shape: CircleBorder(
                      side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 1.0,
                          style: BorderStyle.solid)),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      scoreTeamA();
                       scoreTeamB();
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'win',
                    textScaleFactor: 3,
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: At least for me, is not clear the logic you are trying to apply here. Please write a better explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I believe this is what you are looking for I want to explain some things because I ended up having to change a little bit more than what your question asked because other problems presented themselves once i got the logic you wanted working so here is the code.
Also sorry about the extra styling you can take it out.

```
 int outputTeamA = 0;
  int outputTeamB = 0;
  List<bool> isSelected1 = [false, false];
  List<bool> isSelected2 = [false, false, false];
  int _choiceA = 0;
  int _choiceB = 0;

  void scoreTeamA() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamA += _choiceA;
    });
  }

  void scoreTeamB() {
    setState(() {
      outputTeamB += _choiceB;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ToggleButtons toggleButtons = ToggleButtons(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
      borderColor: Colors.pink,
      children: [
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(
            'Team A',
            textScaleFactor: 3,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Team B ',
          textScaleFactor: 3,
        ),
      ],
      onPressed: (int index) {
        setState(
          () {
            for (int buttonIndex = 0;
                buttonIndex < isSelected1.length;
                buttonIndex++) {
              if (buttonIndex == index) {
                isSelected1[buttonIndex] = true;
              } else {
                isSelected1[buttonIndex] = false;
              }
            }
          },
        );
      },
      isSelected: isSelected1,
    );
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            toggleButtons,
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ToggleButtons(
              borderColor: Colors.pink,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('5 points'),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('6 points'),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text('7 points'),
                ),
              ],
              onPressed: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  isSelected2[index] = !isSelected2[index];
                  switch (index) {
                 //This is the other area I had to make changes
                    case 0:
                      if (isSelected2[index]) {
                        print('true');
                        _choiceA += 5;
                        _choiceB += 5;
                      } else {
                        print('false');
                        _choiceA += -5;
                        _choiceB += -5;
                      }
                      break;
                    case 1:
                      if (isSelected2[index]) {
                        _choiceA += 6;
                        _choiceB += 6;
                      } else {
                        _choiceA += -6;
                        _choiceB += -6;
                      }
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      if (isSelected2[index]) {
                        _choiceA += 7;
                        _choiceB += 7;
                        break;
                      } else {
                        _choiceA += -7;
                        _choiceB += -7;
                        break;
                      }
                  }
                });
              },
              isSelected: isSelected2,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            MaterialButton(
              shape: CircleBorder(
                  side: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1.0,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid)),
              color: Colors.blue,
              onPressed: () {
              //This is the logic you wanted
                if (isSelected1[0]) {
                  setState(() {
                    scoreTeamA();
                  });
                } else if (isSelected1[1]) {
                  setState(() {
                    scoreTeamB();
                  });
                }

                print('TeamA: $outputTeamA');
                print('TeamB: $outputTeamB');
              },
              child: Text(
                'win',
                textScaleFactor: 3,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Once I added the logic you wanted I noticed that if the user selected and un-selected a score then pressed 'I Win' the app acted as though that score was still selected so thats why I made the other changes I made now I don't know if you want to allow more than one score to be selected at a time right now thats how you had the logic set up so thats the route I went. If this is not how you want it to work it shouldn't be that hard to switch some of this logic around. So in conclusion if multiple scores are selected they get added together.

Comment: Thank you , great job.

Comment: if this worked for you can you please accept the answer and upvote the answer if there is anything else I can do for you I'd be happy to help

Comment: i wonder how to  switch the logic to select only  one score at a time ?